# Angularjs disable filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have an ng-repeat like this:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="something in things | filter: {filter1: true, filter2: 'somestring'}">{{ something.title }}</li>
```

In Angular 1.1.5 I used to be able to set filter1 and filter2 to null and no filters would be applied, but since I updated to 1.2.7 this no longer works, how can I programmatically disable the filter?

Comment: Are you using custom filters or angular filters? Which ones?

Comment: filter1 and filter2 are properties on the "something", for example when filter1 = true it should display only the items that are something.filter1 = true

Comment: So wouldn't it make sense that if you say `filter1: null` that it should display only the items that are `something.filter1 = null`? There's probably another way to accomplish what you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was change made in 1.2 (see issue [2797](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2797)) which results in the difference you're seeing. The change was to fix a problem where falsy filter values were not applied correctly. If you initialise the values of filter1 and filter2 to **undefined** instead of **null** then you will the see the same behaviour as you did in 1.1.5.